# Problems with inline edit post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help, I've got script which prints current wordpress quick edit custom field value. But somehow it doesn't and i can't find a way what is wrong with it? Here it is:

```
add_action('admin_footer', 'myown_quick_edit_javascript');

    function myown_quick_edit_javascript() {
        global $current_screen;
        if (($current_screen->post_type != 'imones')) return;

        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function set_myfield_value(fieldValue, nonce) {
            // refresh the quick menu properly
            inlineEditPost.revert();
            console.log(fieldValue);
            jQuery('#imones_miestas').val(fieldValue);
    }
    </script>
     <?php 
    }
```

> console.log(fieldValue);

this prints value in console log but this one - `

> jQuery('#imones_miestas').val(fieldValue);

` doesn't work. Maby i'm doing something wrong? I press quick edit post and my field

> jQuery('#imones_miestas').val(fieldValue);

is empty...

Comment: Are you outputting JS inside a php function?

Comment: Kind of, should i change something?

Comment: Are you expecting the JS to be executed when the php function is called?

Comment: Epodax I want to insert value in this jQuery('#imones_miestas') field, when wordpress quick edit opens up